# Immutable vs Mutable Variable behavior in rust

Tags: rust

I have two separate but similar programs in rust, giving different outputs:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 1;
    while x < 10 {
        println!("{}", x);
        x = x + 1;
    }
}
```

And

```
fn main() {
    let x = 1;
    while x < 10 {
        println!("{}", x);
        let x = x + 1;
    }
}
```

Now the first program prints the numbers 1 through 9, but the second one just loops printing 1's. How does immutability play a role in this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `let x = x + 1;` shadows the outer variable x ,and this variable will have the scope inside the loop only so technically you will get `1` printed . Mutability will play the role when you are modifying the original variable ,declared outside the loop.
What you are doing is creating a new variable x in every iteration in this code

```
while x < 10 {
        println!("{}", x);
        let x = x + 1;
    }
```

If you don't make your x mutable like below

```
fn main() {
    let  x = 1;
    while x < 10 {
        println!("{}", x);
        x = x + 1;
    }
}
```

you will end up with the error -

> error[E0384]: cannot assign twice to immutable variable `x`